# Real Time in Laravel without Node.js

Tags: laravel, real-time

I'm using Plesk and have problems running node.js, I want to create a real-time app in laravel. Is there any way to do it without using node.js or front-end JS framework lick echo, or Pusher?

Comment: https://zachvv11.medium.com/building-a-real-time-chat-application-with-laravel-and-larasocket-c3e377537dc2

Comment: In principle you can manually do what Node.js and those frameworks do, but it's probably going to be quicker and easier to just get node.js to work